# Can a component be used on an onClick of another component that are not parent and child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, I have a navigation drawer component that I am using from material ui, and i am trying to toggle the drawer from inside another component on a button click that is the header.js component.

I have success in toggling it by using the drawer component in the same header.js file, but I want to have the drawer in a separate file and header in a separate file and call drawer when the button in header.js is clicked using the onClick function.

The Header.js file that I have currently done. The IconButton is also from material UI

```
export const Header = () => {

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = event => {
    if (
      event.type === "keydown" &&
      (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(!open);
  };


  return (
   
      <header role="banner" className="header header-beta header-mobile">
          <div className="header__content" >
            <div className="header__nav">
              <div style={{margin: 'auto', paddingRight: '4px'}}>
            
                    <IconButton
                        color="default"
                        aria-label="open drawer"
                        edge="start"
                        onClick={toggleDrawer}  //onclick function that will toggle the drawer
                        className= "round-button round-button--minimal round-button--icon js-trigger-drawer-left"
                      >
                         <span className="round-button__content">
                    <i className="icon icon--sm">
                        <MenuIcon />
                        </i>
                  </span>
                      </IconButton>
                    
              </div>
           </div>  
        </div>
      </header>
  );
};
```

The Drawer component that I have implemented using material UI in the same Header.js file

```
<Drawer
        variant= "temporary"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        onClose={toggleDrawer}
      >
        <div />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        
</Drawer>
```

Now I want to have the drawer component used in a separate file i.e Drawer.js so that it can be called using the onClick function in Header.js like this:

```
export const Drawer = () => {
 
  return (
    <div>
      <Drawer
        variant= "temporary"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        onClose={toggleDrawer}
      >
        <div />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the App.js file that is used to call all the components is:

```
export default function App() {
 
  return (
    <>
    <Header />
    
    </>
  );
}
```

I am stuck if anyone can help me to figure it out.

Comment: Keywords to search: global state management library, redux (personally hate it), react provider, react context, react custom hooks (personally love them)

Comment: I'd suggest to look into React Context in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use React providers and contexts. Here is a template for you

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const DummyContext = createContext({});

export const DummyProvider = (
  {
    children,
  },
) => {
  const [ dummy, setDummy ] = useState(null);
  const ctx = {
    dummy,
    setDummy,
  };

  return (
    <DummyContext.Provider value={ ctx }>
      {children}
    </DummyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useDummy = () => {
  const {
    dummy,
    setDummy,
  } = useContext(DummyContext);

  return {
    dummy,
    setDummy,
  };
};
```

Inside `<OneComponent />`

```
...
const {setDummy} = useDummy()

const handleDummy = () => setDummy(dummy => !dummy)
....
```

inside `<SomeOtherComponent />`

```
...
const {dummy} = useDummy()

dummy changes are observed
....
```

and then

```
<DummyProvider>
 ...
   ...
     <OneComponent />
  ...
 ...
     <SomeOtherComponent />

</DummyProvider>
```

Comment: Thankyou ! I'll check that too

Comment: will the onClick function also work using ContextProvider or not?

Comment: In some button component you will have ```const { setOpen } = useDrawer();``` and then ```onClick={ () => setOpen(true)```, and in the drawer component you will have ```const { open } = useDrawer();``` and then ```<Drawer isOpen={ open } ... />```